# BQ Aquaris E5 Ubuntu edition - Wifi doesn't connect

Tags: networking, wireless, ubuntu-touch, 15.04, aquaris

Just bought a used BQ Aquaris Ubuntu edition.

Data had been factory reset.

Has Ubuntu 15.04 OTA-12.

Finds Wifi networks in range okay but nothing happens when trying connect.

There is a related issue here:
[Aquaris E5 HD (Phone) wifi settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749495/aquaris-e5-hd-phone-wifi-settings)

However the process described there doesn't sound familiar because I just get a list of detected Wifis and when one is selected I get immediately prompted for a password. I don't get "prompted with the WiFi network configuration, select WPA & WPA2 Enterprise, TTLS, MCHAPv2, scroll to the end and check "Remember password"." There is just a prompt with password, see password and the keyboard at the bottom.

Thanks for reading

Comment: The question I asked was related to the auto reconnect not working, which "Pomsky" ;inked to an issue and Thomas confirmed in his last Launchpad comment that it was his fault. From what I can see your issue is that you cannot connect using your new BQ phone. When I have had connecting issues in the past it has always been password related. Click on Advanced (I think it is) and you will see the WPA & WPA2 settings selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine is running Ubuntu 15.04 (OTA-12) and there is no issues at all. Update to the latest version and see if you still have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's been resolved after upgrading to 15.04 OTA-13

Comment: That is great news. One thing I have noticed is that the auto updates on mine do not seem to work that well for updates. I usually have to go in and force an update to take place.